# RegEx - How to select/remove all lines that contains only numbers?

Tags: notepad++

I have a huge list like this. I want to remove the lines that have only numbers. How can I do that?
I'm using **Notepad++**. So, if possible, please give me a solution that will work on **Notepad++**

**List:**

```
dog.belt.b79
dog.food
7902823429
dog.hoodie.722
1898261
dog.collar
dogbelt
80862
doghoodie.89
42111556
```

**I want:**

```
dog.belt.b79
dog.food
dog.hoodie.722
dog.collar
dogbelt
doghoodie.89
```

I tried to Google it. But nothing really helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'd go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\d+\R`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> (at your own risk)

is resulting in:

[image]

Comment: It works, except when last line contains only digits without linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\s*^\s*\d+\s*$
```

and replace it with *empty* string.

[image]

[image]